# Cannot execute rake rspec unit tests with docker compose

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose, rake, rakefile

When I execute `rake spec` against this rake file, docker compose turns up, then it shuts down before the unit tests are executed. **If I remove the last command that runs `docker-compose down` it works fine**

How do I modify the script so it can run `docker-compose up --detach`, then `run the unit tests`, then run `docker-compose down` after the unit tests are completed?

I tried adding a sleep and that didn't work as well.

In my `Rakefile:`

```
Spec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)

# start docker compose.
# we use the system command to wait until docker compose is up and running before starting unit tests
system("docker-compose up --detach")

# run unit tests
task :default => :spec

# stop docker compose
system("docker-compose down")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem not about `docker` but about `rake`. Rake (like make) allows you to add dependencies to a task, and we can use the dependency links to arrange the order of tasks:

```rb
task :docker_up do
 system("docker-compose up --detach")
end

task :docker_down do
 system("docker-compose down")
end

task :default => [:docker_up, :spec, :docker_down]
```

here is the topic you can learn about [how to use rake](https://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html)